# Incorrect positioning of view inside ListView item with a downloadable background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, picasso

I am trying to make a listView of images with written text on those.
Wanted Layout for single item of a ListView looks like below:

[image: Desired layout]

The layout file I wrote looks like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layout_0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#12345A"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16"
    android:text="layout 1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    android:text="layout 2"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it all looks as designed.
However once the image for the background gets downloaded, imageView resizes the ListView item and what happens is:

**layout_2 TextView stays in the same position as it was before**

layout_1 TextView gets centered in the view properly.

Adapter for this ListView:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Activity mContext;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Item> list) {
    super(context, resource, list);
    mContext=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        // configure view holder
        ItemHolder viewHolder = new ItemHolder();

        viewHolder.mImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_0);
        viewHolder.mText1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
        viewHolder.mText2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_2);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ItemHolder holder = (ItemHolder) rowView.getTag();
    Item i = getItem(position);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://lorempixel.com/1080/560/cats/").into(holder.mImage);
    holder.mText1.setText(i.getText1());
    holder.mText2.setText(i.getText2());
    return rowView;
}

private static class ItemHolder {
    private ImageView mImage;
    private TextView mText1;
    private TextView mText2;
}
```

}

As you can see Image is downloaded via Picasso in getView method.

I need some help on how to keep the layout design without setting hardcoded sizes and not breaking ViewHolder pattern completely. Is there a way to refresh this view positioning or any other way to move the layout_2 item to it's proper position?

Comment: Did you tried with LinearLayout?

Comment: I haven't however in my mind it's easier to handle view positioning in RelativeLayout (especially centering) that's why I tried using this first

Comment: Items in the ListView will be sorted based on some factor at some point, however right now these are just stub items.

Comment: The views inside each item of your List are disoriented, is that your issue?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes. Before image gets download it looks like on the image in my quesiton. Right after image for imageview gets downloaded, the view that is set to be centered moves to the center, but the other textview doesn't move at all thus breaking my design.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope it will work.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Item> list
private Activity mContext;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Item> list) {
   inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   mContext=context;
   this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    // configure view holder
    ItemHolder viewHolder = new ItemHolder();

    viewHolder.mImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_0);
    viewHolder.mText1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
    viewHolder.mText2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layout_2);
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);


   // fill data
   ItemHolder holder = (ItemHolder) rowView.getTag();
   Item i = getItem(position);
   Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://lorempixel.com/1080/560/cats/").into(holder.mImage);
   holder.mText1.setText(i.getText1());
   holder.mText2.setText(i.getText2());
   return rowView;
}

private static class ItemHolder {
   private ImageView mImage;
   private TextView mText1;
   private TextView mText2;
}
```